# Fabric js - On mouse over - event target is wrong

Tags: fabricjs

I have created some rectangles and added custom data to it.
On mouse over, i am retreiving the object on which mouse is hover and getting the custom data and shoiwng it on tooltop.
However, the event.target object is wroing.
Its not getting correct the object (object on which mouse is hovering)

See the pic below for illustration[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJWR7.png)

```
station_.platforms.forEach(function (platform_) {
  journey_attrs.top = top;
  var platform = new fabric.Rect(journey_attrs);

  if(subway.subwayConfig.isEndStation(station_.key)) platform.set({opacity: 0});

  top = top + 15;

  platform.set('subwayConfig', { type: 'platform',
    stationKey: station_.key,
    journeyKey:  platform_.journeyKey });

  subway.canvas.add(platform);
  platform_.fabricObject = platform;
})
```

{"fill":"black","width":60,"left":1448,"height":8,"stroke":"‌​RGB(112,210,250)","s‌​trokeWidth":3,"top":‌​364}

Comment: Please show the code on how are you adding the objects on the canvas and positioning them.

Comment: Added the code -

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi-

Comment: What are the properties in journey_attrs?

Comment: {"fill":"black","width":60,"left":1448,"height":8,"stroke":"RGB(112,210,250)","strokeWidth":3,"top":364}

Comment: @Observer -----

Comment: Have you tried to use function setCoords() after you'r setting new properties? Like platform.setCoords();

Comment: Yes, just tried. Not helping.

Comment: What i observe is that the mouse over event is triggered when i move the mouse over object's resizable handles bordering the object. Its not triggerred when i move the mouse over the object itself.

How to go about this ? Any idea ?